# Spark FileNotFound exception while Writing file and reading afterwards

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to do following steps in single job
1) Write a new File 
2) Read the newly created file as Dataset in spark.

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("/tmp/fileName.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("The,first,line");
        writer.println("The,second,line");
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dataset<Row> data = sparkSession.sqlContext().read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("file:///tmp/fileName.txt");
    data.show();
```

Upon which I am getting an issue

```
    Java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/fileName.txt does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I want to achieve both the operation in single job , this job works fine when I run it on the

> local mode

but fails on the

> standalone mode

Comment: You're saving a file named "fileName.txt" and then you're trying to read a file named "vikas.txt"

Comment: @NirHedvat Made correction